# Is this expected Query Performance from CosmosDB for "between" queries on an integer property

Tags: performance, azure, indexing, azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmosdb collection (sql api) that I've populated with documents representing CIDR Network Ranges.

The relevant part of each document is

```
{
        "Network": "31.216.102.0/23",
        "IPRangeStart": 534275584,
        "IPRangeEnd": 534276095,
```

Each CIDR block has it's start and end IP addresses converted to `uint` and stored in hte `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd` properties.

When I run a query to search for a specific entry by it's start range, it works as expected and is quite fast.

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM c WHERE c.IPRangeStart = 532361216 
Request Charge: 3.02 RUs
```

However when I introduce a between query using <= / => operators, it gets VERY expensive.

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM c WHERE c.IPRangeStart <= 534275590 AND c.IPRangeEnd >= 534275590 
Request Change: 1647.99 RUs
```

I've reviewed the index setup on the collection

I've also applied 2 additional integer range indices on the collection for the two specific properties in question. Though there doesn't appear to be a way to check for progress of these indices being applied/created in the background.

Is there something obvious that I might be missing.

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Hash",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "/IPRangeStart/?",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Hash",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "/IPRangEnd/?",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Hash",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": []
}
```

Comment: I know you solved your issue, but... just FYI there's no need to specify the inclusion of the two properties explicitly in your index plan, since you already had a wildcard including *all* properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I solved it. The problem stemmed from the fact that I had a greater than query on one property and a less than query on a different property.

It appears that cosmos was merging the full set of documents that satisfied each independent filter clause.

Since the largest CIDR range in the set was a /18 (16k address block) was able to get it working by saying.

```
Where start <= value 
And start >= value-32786
And end >= value
And end <= value+32768
```